# Create an hidden file with a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, hidden, hidden-files

How can I create a hidden .vbs, .bat or different format file from a .bat file?
I know how to create a file but I have no idea how I can make it hidden.
Is it possible?

Comment: @MatSnow Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, after creating file in bat command, use this attribute to hide

```
attrib +h file name
```